# APEX - Adding two columns and showing the result in a third column

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-apex

From APEX in Object browser, I have created below columns in a table called "Project_Management". Now I always wanted my

- column 4 to display "column1+column3" and
- column 5 to display "column2+column3".

How and where do I declare these from the object browser?

1. Start_date
2. Start_Time
3. Duration
4. End_date
5. End_Time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `interactive grid` region to your page, specify your table `Project_Management` to gather columns you named column1, column2 and column3.[image]

If you change that query to something like:

`select pm.col1, pm.col2, pm.col3, to_char(col1) || ' ' || to_char(col3) as. col4, to_char(col2) || ' ' || to_char(col3) as. col5, from Project_Management;`

you will now see the new concatenated columns also:
[image]

NOTE: Depending on your column types, you may need to use other operations other than to_char or you may want to use DATEFORMAT such as `to_char(col1,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')`;

Comment: can I concatenate two columns along a random integer. For ex - If Col1 value is "ABC", Col2 value is "XYZ, my concatenate column value should be "ABC-XYZ-01". Eveytime a new row is created, the integer value should be random between (1 to 99)

Comment: @VamshiKorde Yes you can, you can either use trigger for that table or data_default for that column and say CONCATCOLUMN := COL1 || COL2 || dbms_random.value(1,99)

Comment: My concatcolumn should have distinct values. Everytime a random number gets generated, will it check if that value is already used in the column? If not, how do we handle that?

Answer (score 0):

That's a **virtual column**.

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (start_date date,
  3     duration   number,
  4     --
  5     end_date as (start_date + duration)        --> this is a virtual column
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (start_date, duration) values (date '2022-01-24', 2);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

START_DATE            DURATION END_DATE
------------------- ---------- -------------------
24.01.2022 00:00:00          2 26.01.2022 00:00:00
                               -------------------
                               END_DATE got its value although it wasn't inserted
```

---

You didn't say which datatypes you used. Oracle doesn't have separate datatypes for date and time; that's just `DATE` which contains *both*.

When you add a number to a date, you're actually adding number of **days** (that's why **24**.01.2022 + 2 = **26**.01.2022).

You said that you'd want to add the same value (`duration`) to the `start_time` column. I don't know what you expect out of that (regardless the fact that there's no `TIME` datatype).